# Unable to login to Tomcat Manager App because of unsuccesful authntication

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat8

I just deployed SpringBoot App WAR file to tomcat 8 server and need to check app status. However,I'm getting:401 Unauthorized while trying to access Tomcat App Manager:

You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.

I've restarted server after adding roles to tomcat-users.xsd.Below is my tomcat-users.xsd:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
   <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
   <user username="manager-gui" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Try adding `manager` to roles. `<role rolename="manager"/>` and `roles="manager-gui,manager"`

Comment: Thanks, tried but no luck

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
   <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
   <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,manager"/>
   <user username="manager-gui" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager"/>

Comment: Which is the URL? Try http://127.0.0.1/manager. Also, this is my tomcat-users.xml if it helps `<role rolename="admin"/>
<!-- <role rolename="admin-gui"/> -->
<!-- <role rolename="admin-script"/> -->
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<!-- <role rolename="manager-script"/> -->
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" />
</tomcat-users>`

Comment: The URL is http://localhost:8080/manager/html. I'll try your xml, thanks!

Comment: Have you really edited tomcat-users.xsd? You should be editing tomcat-users.xml.